# The "Is New" attribute value is empty. Set the attribute and try again

Tags: magento2

When I try add subcategory everytime I get:

```
The "Is New" attribute value is empty. Set the attribute and try again.
```

I try solution with table "is new" set value required to 0 and uncheck box and add 1:

[image]

But this not work for me. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you changed from database then please run below command and try

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

also in admin cache managment you can able to see **2 buttons for flush cache**. please click on both button.

Now try to save category.